# What does this mean: "A persistent start has been called on bundle"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, equinox

While debugging the dropins I'm getting following exception

```
java.lang.Exception: A persistent start has been called on bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120521-2346
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.startBundles(ConfigApplier.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.applyConfiguration(ProfileSynchronizer.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.synchronize(ProfileSynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.synchronize(Activator.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

java.lang.Exception: A persistent start has been called on bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.startBundles(ConfigApplier.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.applyConfiguration(ProfileSynchronizer.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.synchronize(ProfileSynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.synchronize(Activator.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

java.lang.Exception: A persistent start has been called on bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.0.v20120522-1841
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.startBundles(ConfigApplier.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.applyConfiguration(ProfileSynchronizer.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.synchronize(ProfileSynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.synchronize(Activator.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

java.lang.Exception: A persistent start has been called on bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.startBundles(ConfigApplier.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.applyConfiguration(ProfileSynchronizer.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.synchronize(ProfileSynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.synchronize(Activator.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

java.lang.Exception: A persistent start has been called on bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.300.v20110815-1744
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.startBundles(ConfigApplier.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.applyConfiguration(ProfileSynchronizer.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.ProfileSynchronizer.synchronize(ProfileSynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.synchronize(Activator.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Because of the errors like above I guess the eclipse is not recognizing all the plugins and hence showing up only 3 odd perspectives. No Java, PDE perspectives etc. How we can resolve this error?

Comment: Hope the answers in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/277348/) help

Comment: Already googled above link, didn't help much...